# QML,TextArea show json data but can't show \r\n

Tags: javascript, html, json, qml, textarea

In QML,I use TextArea show json data:

```
`TextArea
 {
  id:oldJson
  width: parent.width * 0.4
  height: parent.height
  textFormat: TextEdit.RichText
  text: "<p style='color:red'>"+initDataStr+"</p>"      
//initDataStr is json data like :  initDataStr = JSON.stringify(initDataJson)
}`
```

I want TextArea show like :

`{
    "z1_spindle_speed": 
    {
        "type": "int",
        "value": 6000
    },
    "z2_spindle_speed": 
    {
        "type": "int",
        "value": 6000
    },
    ....
}`
But the result is:

`"{\r\n \"z1_spindle_speed\": \r\n\t{\r\n\t\t\"type\": \"int\",\r\n \"value\": 6000\r\n },\r\n\t\"z2_spindle_speed\": \r\n\t{\r\n \"type\": \"int\",\r\n \"value\": 6000\r\n },....`

What shold i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two issues with your assumption it would be printed multi-lined.

1) the standard is to not print pretty. You can add a `spacer` parameter according to this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
initDataStr = JSON.stringify(initDataJson, null, '\t')
```

2) You are using `TextEdit.RichtText` which resambles HTML. In HTML newlines, abundant spaces and other whitespace is handled smart, basically meaning it is not printed. You can use the `<pre>` tag for this:

```
text: "<pre style='color:red'>"+initDataStr+"</pre>"
```

In conclusion, you should have:

```
TextArea
{
    id:oldJson
    width: parent.width * 0.4
    height: parent.height
    textFormat: TextEdit.RichText
    text: "<pre style='color:red'>"+initDataStr+"</pre>"      
    //initDataStr is json data like :  initDataStr = JSON.stringify(initDataJson, null, '\t')
}
```

Comment: I use ` text: "<pre style='color:red'>"+initDataStr+"</pre>"  `,it make my textarea only have one line an so long,The QML's  TextArea is the same HTML's? I have no idea

Comment: I added what you should put as a result, do you understand that now?

Comment: I got it，thinks!